# Writing Multiple Files from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, streamwriter, sqldatareader

I've created a data reader stream and I'm trying to write the results to a file. Since this table could potentially have millions of records returned, I wanted to write to multiple files so I could open them up in a text editor without the problems, ie. the text editor crashes because the file is too big. Here is roughly my what I have now.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var stream = new FileStream("directoryLocation", FileMode.Create))
{
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "Select * from tblTemp";
    connection.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var tableName = "tblTemp";
        var fileName = tableName + ".txt";
        var recordCount = 0;
        var fileCount = 0;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream.Open()))
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(recordCount == 500000)
                {
                    // Right here. Need to figure out how to close old file start new
                    recordCount = 0;
                    writer.Close();

                    fileName = tableName + "_" + (++fileCount).ToString() + ".txt";
                    writer = new StreamWriter(fileName); // I know this doesn't work. Just sudo code
                }

                recordCount++;
                writer.WriterLine(recordInfo); // recordInfo is sudo code as well
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to move the using writer statement into the reader loop because that would open and close the connection to the file for every record. Any ideas on how to keep my position in the reader and opening and closing files only when needed?

Comment: Just as I posted this I had an idea. Instead of the using writer block could I just manage the StreamWriter myself? Like `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream.Open())` then have try finally blocks to manage the connection.

Comment: Why do you need both a FileSteam and a StreamWriter.  Putting a stream.Open()  inside a new StreamWriter is giving you two opens simultaneously which then causes issues when you try to close and reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close.  You don't need the separate FileStream.  It is okay to create a new StreamWriter in the middle of your loop as long as you dispose of the previous one as needed.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "Select * from tblTemp";
    connection.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var tableName = "tblTemp";
        var fileName = tableName + ".txt";
        var recordCount = 0;
        var fileCount = 0;

        StreamWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (writer == null || recordCount == 500000)
                {
                    recordCount = 0;

                    // Close the previous file if it is open...
                    if (writer != null)
                    {
                        writer.Close();
                        writer.Dispose();
                    }

                    fileName = tableName + "_" + (++fileCount).ToString() + ".txt";

                    // Open the new file...
                    writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                }

                recordCount++;
                writer.WriterLine(recordInfo); // recordInfo is sudo code as well
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Make sure the file gets closed...
            if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm currently refactoring my code with your suggestions and I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would de-couple the logic of rolling the file names out of the code using a custom override of TextWriter.  Something like this completely untested, probably not thread safe, inefficient (it'll currently just write a character at a time!), and likely buggy code:

```
public class RollingFileWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly string _filenamePrefix;
    private readonly string _fileNameSuffix;
    private readonly int _maxRecordCount;
    private Stream _innerStream;
    private int _recordCount = 0;
    private int _fileCounter = 0;

    public RollingFileWriter( string filenamePrefix, string fileNameSuffix = ".txt", int maxRecordCount = 500000 )
    {
        _filenamePrefix = filenamePrefix;
        _fileNameSuffix = fileNameSuffix;
        _maxRecordCount = maxRecordCount;

        _innerStream = new FileStream(
            _filenamePrefix + "_" + _fileCounter.ToString() + _fileNameSuffix,
            FileMode.Create );
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }

    public override void Write( char value )
    {
        _innerStream.Write( Encoding.GetBytes( new[] { value } ), 0, 1 );
    }

    public override void WriteLine( string value )
    {
        if ( ++_recordCount == _maxRecordCount )
        {
            SwitchStreams();
        }
        base.WriteLine( value );
    }

    private void SwitchStreams()
    {
        _innerStream.Close();
        _innerStream.Dispose();

        _innerStream = new FileStream(
            _filenamePrefix + "_" + ( ++_fileCounter ).ToString() + _fileNameSuffix,
            FileMode.Create );
        _recordCount = 0;
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if ( disposing )
        {
            _innerStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can get rid of the outer `FileStream`, and replace the inner `StreamWriter` with the `RollingFileWriter`, and remove all of the other logic from the loop.